# Deobfuscating Javascript Hex Encoded Variables

Tags: javascript, deobfuscation

Now simple hex deob is simple, I am curious if there is a tool to rename usages of variables. For example:

http://pastebin.com/8m6bvaiu

Is there a tool that will take the variable names from the array, and rename usages within the body of the code?

Comment: `$('#abrpm').html($('.de1').html().replace(/\\x(..)/g,function(a,b){return '&#x'+b+';'}))`

Comment: While that's great for deobbing the variable names, but it does not solve the problem of renaming the usages. such as _x3853[12] (random);

Comment: $('#abrpm').html($('.de1').html().replace(/\\x(..)/g,function(a,b){return '&#x'+b+';'}).replace(/\\u(....)/g,function(a,b){return '&#x'+b+';'}).replace(/_0x(....)/g,function(a,b){return '&#x'+b+';'}))

Comment: renaming the usages is a bit harder

Comment: `$('#abrpm').html(h=$('.de1').html().replace(/\\x(..)/g,function(a,b){return '&#x'+b+';'}).replace(/\\u(....)/g,function(a,b){return '&#x'+b+';'}).replace(/_0x(....)/g,function(a,b){return '&#x'+b+';'}).replace(/'/g,"\\'").replace(/\["/g,"['").replace(/"\]/g,"']").replace(/","/g,"','"));
eval($('#abrpm').text().replace(/\n/g,'').split('$')[0])`

Comment: and replace with needed via regex

Comment: What do you mean and replace with needed? You mean per var?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this website, most of the code can be formatted and become readable: http://jsbeautifier.org/

However that leaves an enormous array at the top that contains most of the variables/strings used in the code. To insert its contents throughout the code, you can use the following JavaScript that will search and replace each instance:

```
for (var i=0; i<keywords.length; i++) {
    if (keywords[i].match(/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/)) { // Could be a standalone variable
       // Replace any instances the string is used in an array accessor ['x'] with a dot .x
       code = code.replace(new RegExp('\\['+arrayName+'\\['+i+'\\]\\]','g'),'.'+keywords[i]);
    }
    // Insert as strings throughout code, escaping anything necessary
    code = code.replace(new RegExp(arrayName+'\\['+i+'\\]','g'),'\''+
       keywords[i].replace(/\\/g,'\\\\').replace(/\r/g,'\\r').replace(/\n/g,'\\n').replace(/'/g,'\\\'')+
    '\'');
} console.log(code);
```

Be sure to create three variables for that code, `arrayName` (a string of `'_0x67a5'`), `keywords` (the array), and `code` (the code after the array). In order to accurately contain the code in a string, I recommend using Notepad++ to replace all backslashes, quotes, and newlines (find with extended/regex: `\r\n`, replace with: `\\r\\n\\\r\n`).

This leaves a few hex-named variables, but they're all local to specific functions and are much easier to follow. The result can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/kQjz2T0P

Comment: For reference, this is how I ended up running the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEOjVB

Answer (score 1):

If you do python, deal with the big array at the top using:

```
import re
#first open the file and read into the variable 'text'
result = re.sub(r"\\x([0-9A-F]{2})", lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1), 16)), text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `String.replace(regex,function(found,selected))` method.

```js
h0=$('.de1').text();
h1=h0.split('$')[0].split('=')[1];
h2=h0.slice(h1.length+12);
eval('ar='+h1);
h3=h2.replace(/_0x67a5\[(\d*)\]/g,function(a,b){return '"'+ar[parseInt(b)]+'"'});
h4=h3.replace(/;(?!=['"])/g,';<br>').replace(/\\x(..)/g,function(a,b){return '&#x'+b+';'}).replace(/\\u(....)/g,function(a,b){return '&#x'+b+';'}).replace(/_0x(....)/g,function(a,b){return '&#x'+b+';'})
$('#abrpm').html(h4);
```